# Super class appears to wrongly reference properties of derived class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

In the following python code (I'm using 3.8), an object of class B derived from class A calls methods `bar` and `foo` that access members of the parent class through the `super()` function. Hence, I would expect the same result as calling `bar` and `foo` directly on A. Oddly, what is returned is affected by the parameterization of `p` of B, which should not happen because A should shielded from its children, shouldn't it?! Here is the code to reproduce:

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def p(self):
        return 3

    def bar(self):
        return self.p

    def foo(self):
        return self.bar()

class B(A):
    @property
    def p(self):
        return 6

    def bar(self):
        return super().p

    def foo(self):
        return super().bar()



a, b = A(), B()

print(a.p) # prints 3, OK
print(b.p) # prints 6, OK

print(a.bar()) # prints 3, OK
print(b.bar()) # prints 3, OK, since where accessing super().p 

print(a.foo()) # prints 3, OK
print(b.foo()) # prints 6, NOT OK, because we are accessing super().bar() and expect 3
```

I'm out of my wits here, so if someone could iluminate on the rationale of this behavior and show a way to avoid it, this would be most helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `self` refers to the instance so `return self.p` is effectively saying `return b.p`. `super()` just gets the next class in the MRO and hands its method the instance. It doesn't change the instance in any way.

Comment: It's probably better to use composition instead of inheritance for your use case.

Comment: @JReichardt Are you under the impression that a parent class cannot call a derived classes methods?

Comment: As a hint: my expectation is formed from what I know from C++ where the equivalent example would be https://godbolt.org/z/4a6ao8Ybh  - I always expected `this` and `self` to similarly behaved.

Comment: @JReichardt: Python is a dynamic language. The C++ behavior you expected relies on static typing and static dispatch. Python doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the intricacies of `super`!

`super()` here is a shortcut for `super(B, self)`. It returns a proxy that will look in the class MRO for the class coming before B, so A and `super().bar()` will actually call:

```
A.bar(self)
```

without changing the original `b` object...

And `A.bar(self)` is actually... `b.p` and will give `6`

---

If you are used to other object oriented languages like C++, all happens as if all method in Python were virtual (non final in Java wordings)

Comment: This doesn't really have much to do with `super`, but the fact that `self` doesn't change type depending on which method is using it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I believe that comment makes it clear. Adding a `print("A", self.__class__)` and `print("B", self.__class__)` to the properties `p`  of classes A and B, respectively, shows how the class of self and the class of the function being called differ. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`super().attr` means to look up the `attr` attribue in the parent. If the `attr` is a method, it looks up the method's code (instructions to execute). But that does not modify the passed arguments in any way, it just sets the instuctions.

In Python the `self` is an argument behind the scenes. If `c=C()`, then `c.meth(...)` means `C.meth(c, ...)`, i.e. a call of method `meth` defined in the class `C` with first argument `c` (other args follow, if any). The first arg becomes the `self` argument in the method's implementation. The name `self` is just a convention, not a special keyword)

Back to the question. Here is a simplified program without properties, it behaves the same:

```
class A:
    P = 3 

    def bar(self):
        return self.P

    def foo(self):
        return self.bar()

class B(A):
    P = 6 

    def bar(self):
        return super().P

    def foo(self):
        return super().bar()
```

`b.foo()` invokes `super().bar()`, i.e. the `bar()` in the parent class `A`. That method contains code that simply returns `self.P`. But `self` is `b`, so the lookup returns 6. (In your original program `p` is a property that returns 6)